Build Dpkg from bitbucket pipeline gives "dpkg-deb: error: control directory has bad permissions 777 (must be >=0755 and <=0775)"
I'm trying to build .deb package from the bitbucket pipeline but end up with this error msg.
dpkg-deb: error: control directory has bad permissions 777 (must be >=0755 and <=0775)

tried to change the folder's permission with 755 but it didn't help either. I also tried to build with different Debian docker images but nothing helped.
this is the bitbucket pipeline yaml I use.
image: debian:buster-slim

pipelines:
  default:
    - step:
        name: Build dpkg and push to S3 bucket
        image: debian:buster-slim
        deployment: Test
        caches:
          - pip
        script:
          - apt-get update && apt-get install -y
          - cd ..
          - mkdir process-mgmt-svc
          - cp -rp build/. process-mgmt-svc
          - chmod 755 process-mgmt-svc
          - dpkg-deb --build process-mgmt-svc
        services:
          - docker


The error message tells you what's wrong; how did it change when you changed to correct permissions?

It still has the same error. not sure what it means by the control directory. I only assumed it to be the process-mgmt-svc directory.

I would guess it is referring to the debian directory which contains control (and rules, and some other mandatory files as well as anything else related to the actual packaging).

i was able to build dpkg using following command
dpkg-deb --build --nocheck process-mgmt-svc

--nocheck
       Inhibits dpkg-deb --build's usual checks on the proposed
       contents of an archive. You can build any archive you want,
       no matter how broken, this way.

